# SSO Using API based login (not through UI redirection)

Tags: cookies, csrf, sso

We have 3 different applications which have the same top level domain.

- a.example.com
- b.example.com
- example.com

We have a login mechanism where the user provides a username + password and logs in. Each of these websites wants to have control over the UI / user journey where they capture the user name and password, but there is also a requirement that once the session gets created on any of these apps, it gets shared across other apps. So if you logged in on a.example.com, now when you visit example.com you would already be logged in.

Currently we have a login implementation on example.com, which sets a auth cookie, and uses a double submit cookie approach for CSRF prevention. This cookie for now has SameSite=None. Is there a secure way to extend the current implementation so that we can have a SSO like behaviour across these 3 applications?

Note that:

- each of these applications wants to control the UI for collecting user credentials (in this case, we are ok with that because all of these are trusted applications)
- Since they want to control the UI, they explicitly do not want to go for a solution which requires redirecting to a common UI for login and then redirects back to the specific application.
- We could possibly share the cookie across domains because all of them share the same top level domain, but we have a CSRF requirement as well, which seems difficult to implement in a shared manner

Comment: OIDC providers such as Keycloak allow custom sign in screen for relying party (OIDC client). Setup OIDC client for each web service, in their **Realm Settings** > **Themes**, you can customize the page. This is common in multi-tenancy web services.

Comment: @defalt but this would still require a redirection ?

Comment: Yes. Your requirement is to not have common UI so I assumed common URL is not an issue.

Comment: No, the requirement is to be for each application to control the user experience for login, and not take the user outside their user journey with a redirect and then back to it with a redirect

Comment: What you are wanting is [OIDC ROPC](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/oidc-conformant-authentication/oidc-adoption-rop-flow) which is not recommended to use. Relying Party must not know about user credentials which is why other OIDC flows redirect the user.

Comment: this will allow having a native UI for login, but how would this enable session sharing/ SSO?

Comment: Sub-domain can set session cookies on parent domain.

Comment: yeah, but as mentioned in the question, a domain cookie or master cookie approach is difficult because we expect a csrf token

Comment: You can place a short-lived CSRF token in each sub-domain cookie. Whenever the user will visit any one of them, they will check if the session cookie on the parent domain exists and if it does, a new CSRF token will be issued. E.g `a.example.com` sets a session cookie on `example.com` and also sets a CSRF token in a cookie for `a.example.com`. Now if the user visits `b.example.com`, it can see that the session cookie already exists and issues a CSRF token in a cookie for `b.example.com`.